# What Should We Do About Temporally Localized Lists?

Tags: discussion, questions

In reviewing posts on Money I've found that there are large numbers of questions that have a lists of highly temporally localized answers.  By this I mean the answers are quickly out of date.  For example:

- [Best online broker for research](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2287/best-online-broker-for-research)
- [Best Free Tax Prep software?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5573/best-free-tax-prep-software)
- [Which is the best internet salary estimator?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16106/which-is-the-best-internet-salary-estimator)
- [What is the best internet bank?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3312/what-is-the-best-internet-bank)
- [Best online sites for virtual stock trading?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1711/best-online-sites-for-virtual-stock-trading) <sub>Yikes! I asked this one back in the early days...</sub>

These questions all go out of date quickly.  Online brokers go out of business, change names, and go from being free to paid services.  Tax Prep software quality can change drastically over time.  I don't think we're making the internet a better place by having these out of date questions lying around all over the place, and SE doesn't provide a good mechanism for having the top answers updated routinely.

What should we do about these existing questions, and what should our policy be for these types of questions going forward?

Comment: FWIW, [on another Stack Exchange site these "best" questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=best) might have been closed, since they are inherently open-ended and not a good fit for the Q&A format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These types of questions are not a good fit, precisely because they don't age well.

To me, the fact that Dheer is considering some mechanism to attempt to keep them up-to-date hints at this same issue.

That is, we expect that acceptable, but problematic, questions/answers will be refined by the community.  This can happen when the question is first asked (or the answer is first given).  This also happens after-the-fact, when someone comes across a question/answer that requires correction.

However, that paradigm doesn't work well for things that need regular attention and, to me, it goes against the very philosophy of these sites.  While SEI keeps a tight grip on the reigns, the sites work in mainly decentralized fashion.

For example, moderators on these sites are tasked with being exception handlers.  That is, we are here to handle situations that can't be handled by the provided (decentralized) mechanisms.

We can certainly imagine mechanismd for tracking these questions. However, settings things up so that we accept questions which we know **must** be updated regularly goes against the nature of these sites.

Answer (score 0):

Agree. The problem is compounded as most of the guys who search land up here and see the list outdated and may not come back again ... they guys who know what was best, never come back to this question as it is not visible ...

Some kind of tagging or links from FAQ would help periodically reviewing these question by experts would help ...